# Place points on a parabola at the equal distance

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, graphics, drawing

I need to draw multiple circles placed on parabola.

Currently I come with a naive solution

> ```
> const numberOfCircles = 20
> const curve = 200
> const circleRadius = 10
> const spaceBetween = 5
>
> const width = (numberOfCircles - 1) * (2 * circleRadius + spaceBetween) 
> const a = curve / ((width / 2) * (width / 2))
>
> const points = []
>
> for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++) {
>   const x = i * (2 * circleRadius + spaceBetween)
>   const y = a * (x - width / 2) * (x - width / 2)
>
>   points.push({
>     x: x,
>     y: y
>   })
> }
> ```

with the following result

[image]

However I need circles to be placed on the equal distances on the curve (see picture below).

Is there some not too complicated way to approach this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If we look at your parabola from a mathematical point of view, it's simply the graphical
representation of a quadratic equation in the form:

[image]

In your case though it's shape is based on a given `width` & what you call `curve`. The width is the result
of this equation:

```
const numberOfCircles = 20
const curve = 30
const circleRadius = 10
const spaceBetween = 5

const width = (numberOfCircles - 1) * (2 * circleRadius + spaceBetween)
```

thus the width is **475**.

In your code the value of `curve` represents the maximum vertical position for the parabola.
Mathematically this is the turning point called **vertex** and is the point where the parabola's
direction changes from upward to downward or vice-versa. We can say that it's the height of the
parabola.

[image]

As a side note, in your code curve is given as 30 but based on your screenshots I assume it's 200.

To space something evenly on the parabola we need to know the exact length of the path it describes.
This can be calculated using the following formula:

[image]

which returns the **arc length** of the parabola. `a` and `b` are the height & width respectively. Transfered to Javascript
it can be expressed like:

```
const arcLength = Math.sqrt(width * width + 16 * height * height) / 2 + (width * width / (8 * height)) * Math.log((4 * height + Math.sqrt(width * width + 16 * height * height)) / width) / Math.log(Math.E);
```

To obtain the spacing in-between individual circles we simply divide the arcLength by the total number
of circles -1.

So up to this point we have:

```
const numberOfCircles = 20;
const width = 475;
const height = 200;
const arcLength = Math.sqrt(width * width + 16 * height * height) / 2 + (width * width / (8 * height)) * Math.log((4 * height + Math.sqrt(width * width + 16 * height * height)) / width) / Math.log(Math.E);
const spacing = arcLength / (numberOfCircles - 1);
```

The hardest part is getting the x & y positions for each circle along the parabola's path. We can do this by
'walking' along the path in very small steps, calculate the distance from the current point to it's previous
and sum up the distances. If it exceeds the `spacing`, we know we need to place a circle at the current point.

But how do we walk the path anyway? If we determine that the turning point of your parabola is **not** at
`x=width/2` but at `x=0` e.g.

[image]

which is done by simply shifting all horizontal coordinates by half the width to the left, we can use this neat formula:

[image]

where:

`a` is the result of dividing the height by the square of half the width and has to be a negative number as the parabola
opens downwards

`b` is simply half the width

As we determined the turning point is at x=0, this equation should return 200 at x=0 and 0 at x=width/2.

```js
const width = 475;
const height = 200;
let x = 0;
console.log("x:", x, "y:", -(height / Math.pow(width / 2, 2)) * (x + width / 2) * (x - width / 2));
x = width / 2;
console.log("x:", x, "y:", -(height / Math.pow(width / 2, 2)) * (x + width / 2) * (x - width / 2));
```

Yes, it seems to work. Now it's just a matter of plugging in values in the range from the start of the parabola
at -width/2 to it's end at width/2. This is done by divinding the range in small steps which are controlled
by a constant `steps`. This constant incidentally controls the accuracy of the calculations, so it should be reasonably high e.g. at least double the width of the parabola.

If we put everything together we now have:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let radius = 10;
ctx.fillStyle = "#a1a1a1"

const numberOfCircles = 20;
const width = 475;
const height = 200;
const arcLength = Math.sqrt(width * width + 16 * height * height) / 2 + (width * width / (8 * height)) * Math.log((4 * height + Math.sqrt(width * width + 16 * height * height)) / width) / Math.log(Math.E);
let spacing = arcLength / (numberOfCircles - 1);
const steps = 1000;
let x, y, prevPoint, plotPoint;
let summedDistance = 0;

for (let a = 0; a <= steps; a++) {
  plotPoint = false;
  x = -width / 2 + (width / steps) * a;
  y = -(height / Math.pow(width / 2, 2)) * (x + width / 2) * (x - width / 2)
  if (a < 1 || a == steps) {
    plotPoint = true;
  } else {
    summedDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(x - prevPoint.x), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(y - prevPoint.y), 2));
    if (summedDistance >= spacing) {
      summedDistance = summedDistance - spacing;
      plotPoint = true;
    }
  }
  prevPoint = {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
  if (plotPoint) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x + width / 2 + radius, -y + height + radius, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on finding the mathematical equations to determine this, and went for a iterative approach where binary search is used to drill down to the right parameters to generate the points.

Binary search is used at two levels. A helper function uses binary search to calculate the *next* point on the curve that has a desired distance from a given point on the curve.

This helper function is used to generate the desired number of points on the curve, with a guess value as space between them. When this results in a series where the last point is *too far* on the curve, then the guess is reduced, and otherwise it is increased, again applying binary search.

Here is an implementation where you can interactively choose the number of points and the result is immediately displayed:

```js
function distance(a, b) {
    return ((a.x - b.x) ** 2 + (a.y - b.y) ** 2) ** 0.5;
}

// The main algorithm:
function getParabolePoints(start, summit, numPoints) {
    const end = { ...start, x: start.x + (summit.x - start.x) * 2 };
    const m = (start.y - summit.y) / (summit.x - start.x) ** 2;
    // The parabole function:
    const f = (x) => summit.y + m * (x - summit.x) ** 2;
    const precision = 1 / numPoints;
    
    // Given a point on the parabole, and a required space, 
    // find the next point on the parabole, such that the distance between
    // both points is (close to) the given space.
    function findNext(point, space) {
        let highX = point.x + space;
        let lowX = point.x;
        while (true) { // Binary search
            let x = (lowX + highX) / 2;
            let next = { x, y: f(x) };
            let dist = distance(point, next);
            if (Math.abs(dist - space) < precision) return next;
            if (dist > space) highX = x;
            else              lowX  = x;
        }
    }
    
    // Guess a space, and then produce the points on the polygon with that space
    // between then. Then see where the last generated points ends up. Adjust the space
    // in a next iteration to get a better fit... etc.
    let low = Math.abs(summit.x - start.x) * 2 / (numPoints - 1); 
    let high = (Math.abs(summit.x - start.x) * 2 + Math.abs(start.y - summit.y)) / (numPoints - 1);
    const points = [];
    while (true) { // Binary search
        const space = (low + high) / 2;
        points.length = 0;
        let current = {...start};
        points.push(current);
        for (let i = 1; i < numPoints; i++) {
            current = findNext(current, space);
            points.push(current);
        }
        if (distance(current, end) < 1) break; // Found the right space
        if (current.x > end.x) high = space;
        else                   low  = space;
    }
    return points;
}

// I/O handling:

const input = document.querySelector("input");
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawCircle(center, radius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center.x, center.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawPoly(points) {
    for (const point of points) {
        drawCircle(point, 5);
    }
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function refresh() {
    clear();
    const numPoints = +input.value;
    if (numPoints < 2 || numPoints > 100) return; // Validation
    const start = { x: 10, y: 150 };
    const summit = { x: 300, y: 10 };
    const points = getParabolePoints(start, summit, numPoints);
    drawPoly(points);
}

input.addEventListener("input", refresh);
refresh();
```

```css
div { position: absolute };
```

```html
<div>Num circles: <input type="number" min="2" max="100" value="10"></div>
<canvas width="610" height="160"></canvas>
```